# Is a 16gb class 4 micro sd card enough for hd gaming on Xperia Neo V GB?

Tags: external-sd, performance

I want to expand my storage to 16gb primarily for HD gaming (which the Neo V does so well). I have been offered a great deal for a SanDisk 16GB card Class 4 and wanted to clarify if it is enough for HD gaming, classwise.  I am using Android 2.3.

Comment: Classwise, this may be considered the "absolute minimum". I'd suggest at least Class 6, which should be sufficient.

Comment: I read from a question here that it was pointless to go beyond class 4 for smartphones

Comment: So maybe this requires a technical study. But if you already know the answer, why do you ask? :confused:

Comment: I just wanted some clarifications. Besides that article could be wrong you know :)

Comment: Sure -- and so could I, of course. You may not need the "faster access times" -- but to my knowledge, the higher the class the less energy it "eats". Reason might be the very same shorter access times...

Comment: So is Class 4 good enough for gaming?

Comment: I'm not a gamer, so I feel not authorized enough to answer that :) *I* recommend class 6, see my previous comment for reasons. Maybe someone else gives you the answer you want -- I cannot say more on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specifications your phone has 512MB Memory, which is quite close to the lower limit for actual 3D games like N.O.V.A.3. Because the OS must read the game data into the allocated RAM for the game-process (a lot less than 512MB). The game-data is propably bigger than the total allocated RAM space so Android starts to cache the stuff internally (Internal Flash space, not SD Card).

So after loading the game the SD-Card class/speed isn't the most important part. A faster SD-Card will probably just speed up the loading progress but not the gaming experience itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. N.O.V.A 3 and Modern Combat 2 & 3 work flawlessly